# Noflo I get error when trying to print an input

Tags: noflo

I have app.js that looks like:

```
var noflo  = require("noflo");
var graph = noflo.graph.createGraph("PrintValueGraph");
graph.addNode("output", "Print");
graph.addInitial(100,"output","in");
var network = noflo.createNetwork(graph);
```

And I have a Print.coffee script in the same dir, that has the same code as Output.coffee on the noflo-core  folder.

I get the error: no process defined for inbound node output.

Do u have any idea, what the problem is?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components need to be registered in the `package.json` (or `component.json` for the browser) for the NoFlo ComponentLoader to find them.

See example: https://github.com/c-base/ingress-table/blob/master/package.json#L41

There is also the [grunt-noflo-manifest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-noflo-manifest) package that can automate this for you.

The convention is to keep your components in a `components/` subdirectory inside your project.

Comment: thnx bergie, that was it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the Print component in the package.json

```
"noflo": {
  "components": {
     "Print": "./Print.coffee"
   }
}
```